# Auto increasing numbers in array

Tags: objective-c

i'm just starting out with Xcode and need some help. I have this array set up:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: item1type1, item1type, item1type3, item1type4, item1type5, item1type6, item1type7, item1type8, item1type9, nil];
```

Is it possible to auto-assign numbers to elements in a sequence? The logic is simple: item1type(i), item1type(i+1), item1type(i+2),...

Many thanks

Comment: In first place, don't create 9 almost-identically named ivars, but use an array from day 0.

Comment: Thanks for replys. I am parsing the data with JSON so item1type1 is actually a NSString for parsed object: `[[NSDictionary objectForKey:@"item1"]objectForKey:@"item_1_type_1"]` and so on... I thought this would be the easiest way to do it. If you have any more suggestions, thanks..

Comment: Are you writing your own JSON parser? If so, there are already some really good JSON parser libraries out there to do the work for you. Check this one (recommended in some of the parser comparisons): https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit or do some googling. May save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Give more details on your incoming JSON.

Comment: JSON is coming from a webpage, over a wordpress plugin - [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) Big amounts of nested info, which i want to retreive is stored through ACF Repeater [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/). That is why the output takes up the format metioned above. Number of items or types is not fixed. Anyways, I will check some links and do additional research on JSON parsing as @stevekohls suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many magic numbers in this code, but here you go:

```
// Build an Array of keys @[@"item_1_type_1", @"item_1_type_2", ..., @"item_1_type_9"] programmatically

const int numberOfElements = 9;
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfElements];
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
    [keys addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item_1_type_%d", i]];
}

// Extract chosen keys from JSON Dictionary into an Array, matching the
// order of the keys above.

NSDictionary *subDict = myJSONData[@"item1"];
NSArray *myArray = [subDict objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```